# get top mapped values in pytorch tensor

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to get the top N elements in a tensor.
I have a mapping that tells me how to sort the tensor values

```
values_mapping = {1: 12, 3: 1, 4: 2, 2: 34, 12: 3}
tensor = torch.tensor([1, 4, 12, 2])
tensor.topk(3)
```

here the result should be `torch.tensor([1, 12, 2])` i.e. the top values after mapping them using the `values_mapping`

Is there any way to do so using torch? can we tell torch how to sort the values it gets?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a more elegant solution exists, but you can select the values with the needed keys, select top k items from values, use topk indices to select keys:

```
values_mapping = {1: 12, 3: 1, 4: 2, 2: 34, 12: 3}
tensor0 = torch.tensor([1, 4, 12, 2])
mapping0 = torch.Tensor([(k, v) for k, v in values_mapping.items() if k in tensor0])
topk = mapping0[:,1].topk(3)
top_keys = mapping0[:,0][topk.indices]
print(top_keys)
>>> tensor([ 2.,  1., 12.])
```

Comment: I did something similar. I am looking for pytorch oriented solution. something like the key argument in the sort function

Comment: There is topk, but I doubt that there is a custom topk-like function which accepts extra mapping. What is wrong withe the proposed solution?

Comment: Like I said, I am looking for a pytorch built in solution